# White border around cut selection when using Quick Selection tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I have recently reinstalled Adobe Photoshop CC 2018 after getting a new computer. In the past I could use the Quick Selection tool without any issues but in the new installation I'm facing some issues. Whenever I make a selection and then select "Layer Via Cut" a white border is produced.

This is the options set for the quick selection tool...

[image: Quick selection options]

And this is the white border produced when cut out...

[image: White border]

When I use any other tool such as the magic wand the issue does not occur, this is obviously an issue with the Quick Selection tool. From what I understand it is possible to refine the selection using an option nested within Photoshop but I am preferably looking for a change to the Quick Selection options, this didn't happen two days on my old Photoshop installation.

Does anyone know why this occurs? Is it fixable?

Comment: I'm using CS6, this is exactly how the tool behaves when I tested...

Comment: @Luciano It also does the same in CS4, CC2017, and CC2018

Comment: Is this bug fixed in the new photoshop? The white outline is really annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by cutting the selection.  The Quick Selection tool, by design, makes a slightly feathered selection.  When you do *Layer > New > Via cut*, the feathered selection is cutting (deleting) the selection from the background image, leaving a hole which is slightly larger than the image being created on the new layer.

So, the line which appears white is actually part of the background image where you cut it.

The solution is not to cut.  Instead use *Layer > New > Via copy*, or even just Copy, then Paste.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to cut.
Instead use Layer > New > Via copy, or even just Copy, then Paste.
If you'd make it, that you will watch that border anyway.
For example - load selection again (after coping to new layer that selection region) to bottom one and delete that selection region - we see that border again!

Comment: Hi Дмитрий-Мышков. Welcome to GraphicDesign.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience.